# How to update session attribute

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I have some session attributes being saved. I have a jsp page on which a call to a servlet is made through. This servlet updates one of the session variable but I am not able to see the reflection of these changes in my jsp.Pls help.

In My servlet

```
    List<DriverList> abc = dao.getABC();
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("abc");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("abc", abc);
```

In my jsp

```
function update()
{
    var url = "updateServlet";
    var req = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    success: function()
    {
        latlng = [];
        latlng = [<c:forEach var="test" items="${abc}">
                     [<c:out value="${test.latitude}"/>,<c:out value="${test.longitude}"/>,"<c:out value= "${test.name}" />",<c:out value="${test.cellNo}"/>],
                 </c:forEach> ];

    },
    error: function (status) {
         }

    });

}
```

The value of `${abc}` is same as before. How to get the new value ?

The exact flow -

1. when login servlet is called `abc` value as `sessionAttribute` is set.
2. Now this redirects to base.jsp. I use abc for the first time. Now after every 30 seconds this `update()` function is called. This update function calls a servlet through ajax where the session attribute abc is updated.
3. In the success function of ajax request I want to use this new abc value but getting the old one again.

Comment: Please describe the flow of your requests.

Comment: @Vaishali I have same problem, Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

To access the `abc` variable in the JSP try:

```
${sessionScope.abc}
```

Also note that removing before setting is usually redundant. So:

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("abc");
request.getSession().setAttribute("abc", abc);
```

Can simply become:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("abc", abc);
```

Comment: actually I am setting this attribute once the user loggs in. That is why I used removeAttribute. Also I am able to see the value in jsp but when I make a call to the servlet (ie calling update function of my js) I expect the value to get updated and after that when I use "$abc" I want abc with the new values

Comment: Setting a value with key `abc` in the session map will overwrite whatever value was previously associated with the `abc` key.

Comment: Ok i'll remove removeAttribute, but the problem is still the same

Comment: Didn't `${sessionScope.abc}` do the job? The note for the removeAttribute was not part of the solution.

Comment: No getting the same value.

Comment: @cherovium Is it like that te EL variables value are fir placed on the jsp we cant change through JS ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.
It turned out that when you use

```
HttpSession
```

object in your controller, it shouldn't be annotated using

```
@SessionAttributes
```