# Next button not incrementing variable JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, button

I am currently creating an online quiz in a JSP that uses answers and questions stored in databases. Each question and its possible answers are linked with an integer from 1-20, making 20 questions. To access these questions, I have created stored procedures with an IN parameter called QID.

My question is, how can I create a 'Next' button that increments QID and sends the user to the next question? I have heard about using AJAX, but am unsure how to use it. An example case would be the user answers question 1, then clicks the Next button, QID is incremented to 2, then question 2 is displayed, and so on.

Here is my code (I am aware I should not be using scriptlets in a JSP; this will be resolved after the project has been developed):

```
<% 
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement st = null;

String action;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int score = 0;
int QID;

try {

Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mariadb://ebs-db.eastbarnetschool.com/Kishen", "Kishen","doctor9");
    System.out.println("Connection made");

    CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call GetQuestionTitle(?, ?)}");
        stmt.setInt(1, QID); 
        stmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.execute();
        String description = stmt.getString(2);
        System.out.println(description);
%>
<% 

    CallableStatement answer1 = conn.prepareCall("{call GetAnswer1(?, ?)}");
        answer1.setInt(1, QID); 
        answer1.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        answer1.execute();
        String answerOne = answer1.getString(2);
        System.out.println(answerOne);

    CallableStatement answer2 = conn.prepareCall("{call GetAnswer2(?, ?)}");
        answer2.setInt(1, QID); 
        answer2.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        answer2.execute();
        String answerTwo = answer2.getString(2);
        System.out.println(answerTwo);

    CallableStatement answer3 = conn.prepareCall("{call GetAnswer3(?, ?)}");
        answer3.setInt(1, QID); 
        answer3.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        answer3.execute();
        String answerThree = answer3.getString(2);
        System.out.println(answerThree);

    CallableStatement answer4 = conn.prepareCall("{call GetAnswer4(?, ?)}");
        answer4.setInt(1, QID); 
        answer4.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        answer4.execute();
        String answerFour = answer4.getString(2);
        System.out.println(answerFour);

%>
<%

String chosenAnswer=" ";
if(request.getParameter("button")!=null)
{
chosenAnswer=request.getParameter("button").toString();
}

CallableStatement stmt2 = conn.prepareCall("{call GetCorrectAnswer(?, ?)}");
    stmt2.setInt(1, QID); 
    stmt2.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
    stmt2.execute();
    String CorrectDescription = stmt2.getString(2);
    System.out.println("\nCorrect Answer: " + CorrectDescription);

    if(request.getParameterValues("button") != null) {
       if(chosenAnswer.equals(CorrectDescription)) {
           score ++;
           %>
       <h4 align="center"><font color="green" face="arial">You got Question <%=QID%> correct!</font></h4>
       <%

        }   
            else{
                 %>
                 <h4 align="center"><font color="red" face="arial">You got Question <%=QID%> incorrect!</font></h4>
    <%  
    }   
    }   
%> 
<br>
<br>
<center>
<table border="1" width="500px" bgcolor="lightblue" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="100%">

<form name="Quiz" method="get" action='Quiz.jsp'>

<h1 align="center"><font color="white" face="arial">Quiz</font></h1>
<table border="0" width="500px" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="6">
<tr>
<td width="50%"><font color="steelblue" face="arial" size=4><span style="font-weight:normal"> QUESTION <%=QID%></span></font></td>
<tr>
<td width="100%"><font color="black" face="arial" size=4><span style="font-weight:normal"><%=description%></span></font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>        
1: <input type="radio" name="button" value= "<%=answerOne%>" /><font face="arial" size=3><%=answerOne%></font></td>
    <tr>
    <td>
2: <input type="radio" name="button" value="<%=answerTwo%>" /><font face="arial" size=3><%=answerTwo%></font></td>
    <tr>
    <td>
3: <input type="radio" name="button" value="<%=answerThree%>" /><font face="arial" size=3><%=answerThree%></font></td>
    <tr>
    <td>
4: <input type="radio" name="button" value="<%=answerFour%>" /><font face="arial" size=3><%=answerFour%></font></td>
<tr><td><center>


<%
int pageStart = 1;
String start = request.getParameter("start");
if(start != null)pageStart = Integer.parseInt(start);

%>

<input type="submit" value="Next" name="next" ONCLICK = <%=QID=QID+1%>

<%
if (request.getParameter("next") != null){
    QID ++;
}
%>

</center></td></tr> 
</table>
</form>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: I would recommend learning to use servlets or an alternative as fast as possible. having java code in your jsp file itself will make it an unreadable mess

Comment: You can store your `QID` in [HttpSession](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) and when ever user click on submit just modify that i.e : add `1` to session variable.check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23707987/10606400).

Comment: I have no idea how AJAX works, could you provide a bit more clarity with your answer @Swati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is for Asynchronous approach, meaning you stay in the same page

To go to the next question, you better send the user to the page of the question

```
<input name="qid" type="HIDDEN" value="<%=QID+1%>">
```

Comment: How does this work? Where would I put this in my code?

Comment: Just as another parameter in your JSP. As it is a hidden, wherever it fits you. And remember to remove the if (request.getParameter("next") != null) QID++